# Pandas dataframe tweak

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some data as follows:

```
+-----+-------+-------+--------------------+
| Sys | Event | Code  | Duration           |
+-----+-------+-------+--------------------+
|     |     1 |    65 |             355.52 |
|     |     1 |    66 |              18.78 |
|     |     1 |    66 |             223.42 |
|     |     1 |    66 |             392.17 |
|     |     2 |    66 |             449.03 |
|     |     2 |    66 |             506.03 |
|     |     2 |    66 |              73.93 |
|     |     3 |    66 |             123.17 |
|     |     3 |    66 |              97.85 |
+-----+-------+-------+--------------------+
```

Now, for each `Code`, I want to sum the `Durations` for all `Event = 1` and so on, regardless of `Sys`. How do I approach this?

Comment: Group by Event and Code and aggegate with sum().

Answer (score 0):

As DYZ says:

```
df.groupby(['Code', 'Event']).Duration.sum()
```

Output:

```
Code  Event
65    1         355.52
66    1         634.37
      2        1028.99
      3         221.02
Name: Duration, dtype: float64
```